# Is $A \leqslant_P B \iff A \in \mathsf{P}^B$? If not are there counter-examples?

Tags: complexity-theory, oracles

The way I think of reducing problem $A$ to problem $B$ in polynomial time, i.e. $A \leqslant_P B$,  is that you assume an efficient solution to $B$ which is enough to solve $A$. Now, this is suspiciously similar to $A \in \mathsf{P}^B$. I'm confident that $A \leqslant_P B \implies A \in \mathsf{P}^B$ but is the reverse implication true? If not, can you provide some counter examples?

Similarly can anything be said about the statement:
$$
A \leqslant_L B \iff A \in \mathsf{L}^B
$$

Edit: Clarified $\leqslant_P$ is polynomial reduction and fixed notation for PTIME, LOGSPACE.

Comment: Thanks, but there is still one thing missing: are you talking about **many-one** reductions, i.e., $\exists f\in \mathsf{FP}: x\in A\iff f(x) \in B$ (FP contains functions computable in polynomial time)? Then the answer below is correct, if you consider Turing reductions both expressions are synonyms. Your first sentence sounds more like Turing reductions.

Comment: Essentially, your question is **very** close to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24580/what-is-the-difference-between-turing-reductions-and-many-one-reductions .

Comment: @frafl I am considering many-one polynomial reductions. But yes, it is the closeness of these ideas that caused me to investigate if there was some overlap. Thanks for the question, I will check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\le_P$ is a polynomial many-one reduction (as opposed to a Turing reduction), the statement is incorrect.

For example, for any language $L$ we have $\overline{L} \in P^L$ (and in fact, in $O(1)$ time and space as well, so this is also an example for logspace many-one reductions)

But obviously if we take $L=\mathrm{Halt}$ to be the halting problem language, we wont have that $\overline{L} \le_P L$ since $\mathrm{Halt}\in \mathsf{RE}$ but $\overline{\mathrm{Halt}}\notin \mathsf{RE}$ and $\mathsf{RE}$ is closed under $\le_P$.